# Implication of Area Formula (Measure Theory)

Tags: geometric-measure-theory, hausdorff-measure

In the book **Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions** of *Evans and Gariepy* has the theorem:

**Theorem (Area Formula)**: Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be Lipschitz, $n\leq m$. Then for each $\mathcal{L}^n$-measurable subset $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$,      $\int_A Jfdx=\int_{\mathbb{R}^m} \mathcal{H}^0(A\cap f^{-1}(y))d\mathcal{H}^n(y)$.

Where, $\mathcal{H}^n$ and $\mathcal{H}^m$ are Hausdorff measure. $\mathcal{H}^0$ is counting measure. $J(f)$ is the Jacobian of $f$.

After the theorem has the remark,

**Remark**: Using the Area Formula, we see $f^{-1}(y)$ is at most countable for $\mathcal{H}^n$ a.e $y\in \mathbb{R}^m$.

**My question**: How to prove this remark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix a compact set $K$ in ${\bf{R}}^{n}$, then $\displaystyle\int_{K}Jf(x)dx<\infty$ and hence $\displaystyle\int_{K}\mathcal{H}^{0}(K\cap f^{-1}(y))d\mathcal{H}^{n}(y)<\infty$, so for $\mathcal{H}^{n}$-a.e. $y$ in $K$, $\mathcal{H}^{0}(K\cap f^{-1}(y))<\infty$, so $K\cap f^{-1}(y)$ has finitely many elements. Now write ${\bf{R}}^{n}$ as the union of an increasing sequence of compact sets, and note that the countable union of null sets is still null, and the countable union of finite sets is of at most countable, the assertion follows.

Comment: How did you conclude that $\int_K Jf(x)dx<\infty$?

Comment: The proof of the area formula in that book supplies sets for which the integrand is bounded. These cover the compact set, so we can pick a finite subcover and then take the maximum of the bounds. Now the integral must also be finite.