# Application of Area Formula

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Let $n,k$ be positive integers satisfying $k\le n$, $\varphi\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function whose support is compact and $f\colon\mathbb{R} ^k \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be an injective Lipschitz continuous map.

In the book "Rectifiable Sets, Densities and Tangent Measures" of Camillo De Lellis, he uses the following equation;

\begin{equation}
\int_{f(\mathbb{R}^k)} \varphi (x) d\mathcal{H}^k (x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^k} \varphi(f(y))Jf(y)d\mathcal{L}^k (y)
\end{equation}
where $\mathcal{H}^k$ and $\mathcal{L}^k$ are the $k$-dimensional Hausdorff measure and the $k$-dimensional Lebesgue measure, respectively.

How to prove this equation? (We can use [the Area Formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2726992/539553).)

Comment: I think they must be normalizing $\mathcal H^k$ so that $H^k([0,1]^k\times \{0\}^{n-k}) = 1$. I usually see it defined without that normalization. Also, you need to have $f$ injective. For example if $k = 2, n = 3, f$ could be a sheet that folds over and back onto itself, looking like an ankh shape without crossbar from the side. In that case the LHS would only pick up contributions from the doubled region once, while the RHS would pick them up twice.

Comment: @PaulSinclair You’re absolutely right. I’ll add the injective condition.

Comment: To prove this, break up the domain of $\phi$ into sets for which $\phi$ is approximately constant. On each of these sets, approximate the integral by treating $\phi$ as constant, and use the Area formula to get the same approximation of the other integral. Add the integrals over all the pieces to get the integral over the whole.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I understand. Thank you.

Comment: It would actually be better to divide up the domain of $\phi \circ f$ for this instead of the domain of $\phi$.

Comment: I would say that divide into pieces where the <derivative> is almost constant. Because then image of that piece under our map will have measure almost equal to the measure of the piece under the linear map. For linear map the factor is exactly the Jacobian.  Proof can be found in Evans and Gariepy's book.